# CSS Table Layout in Firefox with overflown contents doesn't get scrolled

Tags: css, html, firefox

basically, I need my CSS table, containing top & bottom to be scrollable (as it happens to be in WebKit browsers), rather than going through the floor as it's happening in FF...

http://jsbin.com/cokeyila/1/edit

Html:

```
<html lang="EN">
<head>
    <title>ff_test</title>
</head>

<body id="body" style="padding: 0; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div id="fixed_header" style="left : 0; top: 0; position:fixed; height: 40px; background-color: #ccc; width: 100%;">
        Fixed Header
    </div>
    <div id="header" style="width: 100%; height: 104px; margin-top: 40px;">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: green;">
            Banner
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 145px; bottom: 5px; left: 0; right: 0; padding: 5px 95px 5px 5px; background-color: yellow;">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table;">
            <div style="display: table-row;">
                <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
                    <div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                        <div style="display: table-row; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                            <div style="display: table-cell; width: 100%; height: 100%; vertical-align: top;">
                                <div style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                    <div style="display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: blue;">
                                        <div style="display: table-row">
                                            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                                                <div style="height: 100px; background-color: gray;">top</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="display: table-row">
                                            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                                                <div style="height: 1000px; background-color: lime;">bottom</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="left: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; bottom: -195px; height: 200px; background-color: gray;">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You say, "basically, I need the table". Why dont you use a TABLE?

Comment: well, a CSS table:) I don't own the layout, I just need to get FF version working.

Comment: I'm hoping for FF just needs a small "height: auto" somewhere just to help it going:)

Comment: table or display :table & similar have the main specifity to adapt to the content it holds, shrinking or expanding to it. it is not meant to show scrollbars. table-layout can only fix width. overflow will only hide

Comment: @GCyrillus how come it works in webkit browsers (chrome & safary)? I think FF doesn't realize the table is overflown.

Comment: @user1514042 chrome, opera, safari, IE11 allows to style map and areas too, are these meant to be styled ?. it is not because it does that it has . Same probleme with willing to style form elements , some browsers allows some things and some others not. basicly a table is not meant to show scrollbar unless you reset  display to a value that do not belong to table specifity and that accepts it :).

Comment: I hear you, the stuff I'm taking about is really basic though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same things as described in

[CSS table cell overflow is ignored by FF & Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778488/css-table-cell-overflow-is-ignored-by-ff-opera/12779165#12779165)

works.

Basically, in order to see a scrollbar in the overflown table-cell it takes building the following:

```
...
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table-cell;">
   <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
      <div style="top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; overflow-y: auto;">
         <div style="height: 5000px;">Overflown content, which doesn't corrupt parent table layout</div>
...
```