# overflow auto not working in ie with 100%

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, overflow

This is my code.
I want the div with class=main to overflow vertical when it exceeds the height limit i set by percentage. Overflow auto doesn't work in internet explorer. I am going crazy with the microsoft sh##t.

```
<body>
<table class="container" border="0">
<colgroup>
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
<col width="5%"><col width="5%">
</colgroup>

<tr class="header"> 
    <td colspan="1"></td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <a href=""></a>
    </td>
    <td colspan="15">
        <?php include '../include/menu.php';?>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="top_gap">
    <td colspan="20">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr class="title">
<td colspan="1"></td>
<td colspan="11"></td>
<td colspan="7" valign="bottom"  style="height:0;" >
<div class="transparent">
        <?php   DisplayTitle($option,$mysqli);  ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1"></td>
</tr>


<tr class="main">   
    <td colspan="1"></td>
    <td colspan="11"></td>
    <td colspan="7" valign="top"  style="height:0;" >
        <div class="main">
        <div class="transparent">
            <?php DisplayText($option,$mysqli);?>   
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="bot_gap">
    <td colspan="20">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr class="footer" nowrap>
    <td colspan="20"><p></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Here is the css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Century Gothic, Arial, Courier New, Sans-Serif; 
    font-size: 0.5em;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table.container{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
tr.header{
    height:15%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
tr.title{
    height:10%;
}
tr.main{
    height:60%;
}
tr.footer{
    height:5%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
tr.top_gap{
    height:5%;
}
tr.bot_gap{
    height:5%;
}
div.main{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
div.transparent{
    padding:3em;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: `<td colspan="7" valign="top"  style="height:0;" >
        <div class="main">`  ?? this is `height : 0` and td doesn't care, it grows . do you have a link / fiddle/ codepen ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W34wy/4/

Comment: duplicate ? lok at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778488/css-table-cell-overflow-is-ignored-by-ff-opera/12779165#12779165